# What is 'non-expansion work' and how does ΔG represent the maximum non-expansion work that can be extracted in a reversible process?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

I have just learned about Gibbs free energy and how its value indicates the change in entropy of the universe and can thus be used to find the spontaneity of a reaction. However, I found this other interpretation of Gibbs free energy on Wikipedia that I don't get at all.

> The Gibbs free energy is the maximum amount of non-expansion work that can be extracted from a thermodynamically closed system (one that can exchange heat and work with its surroundings, but no matter). This maximum can be attained only in a completely reversible process. When a system transforms reversibly from an initial state to a final state, the decrease in Gibbs free energy equals the work done by the system to its surroundings, minus the work of the pressure forces.

What exactly does 'non-expansion work' mean in the context of, say, a gas? How can it even do work other than by expanding or contracting?

Secondly, I thought the extractable energy during a reaction was ΔH( *heat transferred during a physical or chemical reaction carried out at constant pressure*). If that is actually ΔG=ΔΗ-TΔS instead, what kind of energy does 'TΔS" represent? I know that it is equal to the heat transferred into or out of the system **if the process is done reversibly** but I don't understand how that's relevant here.

Lastly, Wikipedia mentions that this maximum can only be extracted by a reversible process. How exactly would you extract this? For example, if a reaction has a ΔΗ=-50 and ΔG=-75, how do you get the extra 25 units of energy?

Comment: Regarding your second question you may find answers in many related Q&As on the site, for instance: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/16687/thermodynamically-reversible-processes-how-does-an-infinitesimal-step-make-a-pr?rq=1

Comment: See also: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/112900/gibbs-free-energy-and-maximum-work?rq=1

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/33816/maximum-useful-work-from-a-process?rq=1

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/29180/what-is-the-precise-definition-of-maximum-work-in-the-context-of-electrochemistr?rq=1